# Slicing a list at a certain point, getting the 3 elements before it

Tags: python, list

I'm currently trying to slice a list I have at certain points. At this slice, I want to grab the three elements in the list before. I know I can use [-3:] to get the three elements at the end, like this:

```
lengths = [1,5,4,3,6,4,6,7,4,7,3]

selected = lengths[-3:]

print (selected)

[4, 7, 3]
```

But say I wanted to do it at position 5, so my output would be:

```
[4,3,6]
```

How would I go about this? I tried using:

```
selected = lengths[-3:5]
```

But it returns nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer:

Turns out I was getting my negatives and going backwards confused. I can use the endpoint `5` to get the three values like this:

```
selected = lengths[5-3:5]

print (selected)

[4,3,6]
```

Comment: why not `lengths[2:5]` ?

Comment: You are getting caught up in using negatives to go backwards. `list[start:end]` you know your `end` so you just want to calculate your `start`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out! I can use the endpoint like this `lengths[5-3:5]`

Answer (score 1):

If you know your end index:

```py
end_index = 5
selected = lengths[end_index - 3: end_index]
```

This gives: [4,3,6] as output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here you want the first three elements from the position -9 in the list, but you are try to select the elements from position -3 to 5 which is not possible because during negative indexing the parameter after the colon(:) must be lesser in value for it to actually select anything.

The right and easy way to do this is by :

```
lengths = [1,5,4,3,6,4,6,7,4,7,3]
print(lengths[2:5])
```

which yields

```
[4, 3, 6]
```

The other way is by using the negative indexing

```
lengths[-9:-6]
```

Here the value from position -9 that is 4 to -7 that is 6 will be selected.

Both of these yield the same results, but personally I would use the first method(positive indexing).

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to change the position and/or number of values to retrieve before that position, you could use a little function:

```
def last_n_elements(lst, n, position):
    new_list = lst[:position]
    return new_list[-n:]


lengths = [1, 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 3]
print(last_n_elements(lengths, 3, 5))
print(last_n_elements(lengths, 2, 6))
```

which gives you:

```
[4, 3, 6]
[6, 4]
```